# Convert string (in scientific notation) to float

Tags: python, string, floating-point, data-conversion

I'm trying to import a large .csv file containing text and numbers using `genfromtxt` in numpy.  I'm only interested in two columns. I have most of the import sorted out with:

```
def importfile(root):
    data = root.entry.get()
    atw = np.genfromtxt(data, delimiter=",",
                        skip_header=1,
                        skip_footer=2,
                        autostrip=True,
                        usecols=(25,26),
                        dtype=("|S10"))
    elem = atw[:,0]
    concs = atw[:,1]
        
    print(elem)
    print(concs)
```

With output for `elem` and `concs` respectively:

```
['Na2O' 'MgO' 'Al2O3' 'SiO2' 'P2O5' 'SO3' 'Cl' 'K2O' 'CaO' 'TiO2' 'Cr2O3'
'MnO' 'FeO' 'NiO' 'Cu2O' 'ZnO' 'Ga2O3' 'SrO' 'Y2O3']

['3.76E+00' '1.31E+01' '1.14E+01' '4.04E+01' '1.24E+00' '5.89E-02'
'2.43E-02' '1.53E+00' '1.49E+01' '2.87E+00' '6.05E-02' '1.96E-01'
'1.17E+01' '3.69E-02' '8.73E-03' '1.39E-02' '1.93E-03' '1.88E-01'
'5.58E-03']
```

I have tried many different things for converting the `concs` string into a float, but it doesn't seem to like the fact that the concs are in scientific notation... is there a way to turn the `concs` values into a float?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The `float` function can do this:

```py
>>> float('1.31E+01')
13.1
```

or for a list:

```py
>>> map(float, ['3.76E+00', '1.31E+01', '1.14E+01'])
[3.76, 13.1, 11.4]
```

Comment: Obligatory list comprehension approach: `n = ['3.76E+00', '1.31E+01', '1.14E+01'] [float(i) for i in n]`

Comment: float(i) won't work for me. I have a mixed list and I want to convert it. Not sure what should I use if I don't want to split it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 with open( datafile,'r' ) as inData:
     for line in inData:
          j = list( map( float,   filter( None  , [ x for x in line.strip().split(',') ] )) )
```

Just mentioned generally, as it solves a similar problem that brought me to this page.

Answer (score 0):

MAybe that will be helpful for anybody, I had similar problem and I've  found on stackoverflow about applying pandas to_numeric to DataFrame columns including replacing commas with dots

```
import re
import pandas as pd
atw[cc] = pd.to_numeric(atw[cc].apply(lambda x: re.sub(',', '.', str(x))))
```

Answer (score -3):

Having such list of scientific notations,  you can also do this:

```
1. a = [9.0181446e-01, 1.3179450e-02, 4.3021311e-04, 2.3546994e-03, 3.6531375e-03, 7.8567989e-02]
2. max(a)
```

Output will be: 0.90181446