# Remove scientific notation from pandas column containing both string and float

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am unable to remove scientific notation from a column containing both string and non-string entries.

When I import a dataset using read_csv, one of the column shows the following:

```
0           1.9157E+11
11          1.9157E+11
12          1.9157E+11
13          1.9157E+11
14          1.9157E+11
         ...      
37444    19156794-1005
37445    19156794-1004
37446      19156791023
37447    19156794-1003
37448    19156794-1003
```

While all of the entries are encoded as strings, some rows contain only numbers (hence they are converted to scientific notation) and some rows contain "-" (hence they are displayed properly).

When I print `dataframe['column'][11]`, I get `'1.9157E+11'`, which is a string.

I am unable to use `apply(float)` to the whole column because some of the entries contain '-', and therefore cannot be converted to string.

There was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23636509/python-convert-string-in-scientific-notation-to-float) asked as well but the OP faced the same problem (see comments under solution) and no resolution was achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code, if you need to convert all the convertable values and leave others as is:

```
def try_float(x):
    try:
        return float(x)
    except ValueError as e:
        return x

series.apply(try_float)
```

Comment: Is there a way to write this in lambda function? Just curious

Comment: @johnconnor92 No, but [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451531/python-try-catch-block-inside-lambda) may help you

Comment: Alright, thank you! Problem solved. I am not familiar with using 'except' clause yet, that's why I don't know how to write this function.

Comment: @johnconnor92 try-catch syntax is not hard. The function runs `try` code, and in case it gets `ValueError`, it runs `except ValueError` code.