# Convert scientific notation (letters in decimal values) when reading excel with pandas.read_excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have an excel document with values like: `0.0000595628`

When I am using `print(float(row['% of total    failures2']))`, I get the value `5.95628e-05`

Even reading it using only `print(row['% of total    failures2'])`, I do get the same `5.95628e-05`

How can I convert that value with to show all of its decimals?
The reason is because when I try to insert the value in teradata, the column is a string and it will insert it as such.

[image]

**Update:** Even if I change the column to Number in excel, I do get same:`5.95628e-05`

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Convert string (in scientific notation) to float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23636509/python-convert-string-in-scientific-notation-to-float)

Comment: Not trying to be sarcastic here, but your example is showing the same number of decimals. `0.0000595628` and `5.95628e-05` both show `595628`. So is the problem more that you don't want to see it in scientific notation?

Comment: Yes, I have converted it using:    row['% of total    failures2'] = "{:.10f}".format(float(row['% of total    failures2']))

Comment: Are you inserting the value into the DB and then reading from the DB?  If so, can you `CAST` it as a `FLOAT` when you do your `INSERT`?

Comment: @ravioli I am inserting into DB and since the column is string, I have the scientific notation as string. The thing is when you take that string to place it into a float again, it goes all wrong. So I had to format it to 10 decimals as string and then insert it as string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converted the row value to 10 decimal places with

```
row['% of total failures2'] = "{:.10f}".format(float(row['% of total failures2']))
```